# Need clarification on preg_match in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm kinda of new to PHP, can you please clarify about the below preg_match.

```
preg_match("/^(9)\1+$/",$value);
```

Comment: There are tools that can explain regular expressions: [Is there anything like RegexBuddy in the open source world?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world) and [Any good regular expression creator software or online tools to create Regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910220/any-good-regular-expression-creator-software-or-online-tools-to-create-regular-ex)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will match a string that consists of two or more `9`s.

The regex is weird, and not typical of its intention IMO. I'd write it as...

```
/^9{2,}\z/
```

Comment: Perhaps better say "consists of" instead of "contains".

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Yeah, you're right, it's ambiguous. I'll update it, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

preg_match($arg1, $arg2);

$arg1 - regular expression
$arg1 is being searched/matchedin $arg2

for more help refer this link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

for regular expressions: http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html

In the example you gave:
The regular expression 
"/^(9)\1+$/" - Starts(^) with 9 and have more than 1 (\1+ which means 2 or more) 9's and ends($) with 9

So this is being searched in the $value. Hope it is clear.